# How to make snakeyaml and GStrings work together

Tags: groovy, snakeyaml

When I'm trying to use snakeyaml to dump out Yaml out of Groovy interpolated strings, it ends up printing a class name instead.

For example:

```
@Grab(group='org.yaml', module='snakeyaml', version='1.16')

import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
def a = "a"
def list = ["$a"]   
def s = yaml.dump(list)
```

Prints:

```
- !!org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GStringImpl
  metaClass: !!groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl {}
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that GStrings get transformed to Strings when they used and I suspect snakeyaml uses some sort of introspection to determine the class of the object.

Is there a better solution than calling `toString()` on all GStrings?

Answer (score 4):

Try to create a new Representer :

```
public class GroovyRepresenter extends Representer {
  public GroovyRepresenter() {
    this.representers.put(GString.class, new StringRepresenter());
  }
}

Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new GroovyRepresenter())
...
```

Comment: Since GString is an abstract class, I had to use multiRepresenters:
`def representer = new Representer() {{                    this.multiRepresenters.put(GString, this.representers.get(String))   }}`

Answer (score 1):

You could add type info to your variables

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
def a = "a"
String aStr = "$a"
def list = [aStr]   
def s = yaml.dump(list)
```

Comment: That will dramatically increase the size of my code, `toString()` seems simpler. For example if I had `def list = ["john $a", "frank $a", "simon $a"]` I would have to define 3 variables.

Comment: You could write a method that takes String arguments, and build a list from them? `def list(String... args) { args as List }`